# VSCode not resolving installed python dependencies

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv, pylance

I have a `python` project for which I have activated a `virtualenv` and installed everything in `requirements.txt`.

This has been done manually through

```bash
python -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

and

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

However the VSCode fails to resolve the additional dependencies (and marks the corresponding imported libraries with a squiggled line as per the screenshot below)

Is there something additional that needs to be configured on VSCode level to make this work?

[image]

Comment: which `pip` did you use for the install

Comment: `▶ pip --version
pip 24.0`

Comment: This is an interesting issue, and one that I suspect does not have a simple solution. The only thing I can suggest is that after you activate the `venv`, you then start VSCode from that command prompt. But it may be, that VSCode already has its Python environment details set and will not recognise these settings. You need to do some more detailed investigation of all the settings that VSCode is using when it runs a Python application.

Comment: but is it the `pip` of the virt env

Comment: how can I check this (or to expand on this, how to ensure the requirements are installed via virtualenv's `pip`?)

Answer (score 1):

This was usually caused by python interpreter.

You could use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose your python interpreter which you installed the package in.

If you ensure that you've chosen the correct python interpereter, you could add the following codes to your settings.json:

```
"python.analysis.extraPaths": [
    "/path/to/directory/where/requests/is/installed"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you activate your virtual environment.

This can be done by executing the activate script in the terminal:

*/pathtovenv/venvname/scripts/activate*

Comment: I have activated it but without any effect whatsoever

Comment: Check the Lib/site-packages folder in your venv to make sure the dependencies are actually there. Maybe you installed to something other than the venv.